# Testing performance of WordPress files

Tags: testing

I would like to test the performance of PHP files in my installation, to find any bottlenecks. I already use plugins like Debug Queries and WPDB Profiler to watch the SQL Queries being generated, but I would like something that shows me the execution time of each php file to identify if some plugin is not optimised. Is there any plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. And even if there was, it would be probably useless anyway.

You would get incorrect results, because a .php file might call slow functions from WordPress core files, and there are a lot of situations like this.

You could try using the [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) extension, it's pretty close to what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, I do use xdebug, but it doesn't show me the execution times, the only way for me to find a bottleneck would be to visually see some bad code, but it's more difficult like that.

Comment: What about something like this? http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark/redirected

Comment: Looks simple timing script. You can start the timer inside a plugin function that you think is slow, set up markers trough it if you wish, then stop the timer when function ends and display the results :)